# .NET MAUI Blazor POS App Freezing Issue when Using Physical Barcode Scanner on Android

Tags: android, .net, blazor, maui

I'm working on a Point of Sale (POS) application using .NET MAUI and Blazor, specifically targeting Android devices. Everything has been going well so far, but I've encountered a frustrating issue that's got me stumped.

Whenever I connect or disconnect a physical barcode scanner to my Android device while running the POS app, it freezes. The app becomes unresponsive, and I have to force close it and restart it to continue working. This happens both when I connect and disconnect the barcode scanner.

**My Questions:**

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue when using .NET MAUI and Blazor for Android development?

Are there any known compatibility issues with specific barcode scanner devices?

Any recommendations for debugging or profiling tools that might help pinpoint the problem?

I'd greatly appreciate any insights, advice, or suggestions you can provide. If you need more specific details about my code or setup, please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help!